# How to print one array value of an PDO database select query?

Tags: php, select, pdo

I am using this PDO wrapper class: http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/#select and now just have troubles to echo an object.

This is the method declaration:

```
<?php
//select Method Declaration
public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*") { }
?>
```

My query goes like this which prints the result array:

```
<?php
$title = 'title_'.$GLOBALS['SelectedLang'];

$results = $GLOBALS['db']->select("news", $title != '', "", $title);
print_r($results);
?>
```

But how do I echo one table field of the query? Which in old school mysql I would have done like this:

```
<?php
$row = @mysql_query($results);
echo $row->$title;
?>
```

The output for the print_r is:
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [title_en] => englisch ) )

Comment: The statement `$title != ''` can't be doing what you think it does, btw. The output from your print_r would also be helpful.

Comment: are you able to get back all the titles or is this returning the entire table? Or are you trying to get one specific title?

Comment: well if the function returns object than $results->columnName hardcode second parameter to see if you get results

Comment: this is the output of the print_r:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title_en] => englisch ) )

Comment: so it's just echoing out the array. you can either dig into the array like print_r($results[0]); or try a json_encode

Comment: so you get it like $result['title_en']

Comment: @zazvorniki - he gets result it is  -englisch

Comment: @vodich - $results['title_en'] brings this error: Notice: Undefined index: title_en in D:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\pages\news\NewsActions.php on line 15

Comment: If you did print_r($results) and get ['title_en'] as index  than you can't have undefined index. How are you echoing it ? Can you do foreach($results as $r){echo $r['title_en'];}

Comment: Did you not miss the _ from $_GLOBALS[]....why are you using globals surely there's a better way of doing it. Also see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: @vodich - yes, the foreach loop works

Comment: @Dave- no he doesen't want superglobal but you are right not the best practice to name vars like this

Comment: @vodich - what would be the best practice for the vars?

Comment: personally i'd use a define when a userlogs in define a lang define then you can put it in everywhere required without having to reference vars everywhere. slightly less overhead bit faster much easier to read and not get confused.

Comment: @Dave - Thanks, but except performance issues superglobals are ok? no security issue there?

Comment: You're not using superglobals just something thats named very similar to a superglobal all caps etc you're using $GLOBALS the super is $_GLOBALS.  Its bad naming convention to use a var of a name similar to superglobals else you can get confused (as I just did) I think most servers these days have superglobals restricted to just PGS though i'm not 100% on that someone else will probably know better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want to echo your query results you should do it in a loop:

```
foreach($results as $r){echo $r['title_en'];}
```

Comment: and as a side question: is there a way to echo like this: $r->title_en ? Because that's what I am used to :)

Comment: Only if method returns object instead of array